# remove only the last extension from file name

Tags: bash, file, edit, tcsh

I have file names that look something similar to this

```
name_1.23.ps.png
```

or

```
name_1.23.ps.best
```

or

```
name_1.23.ps
```

I want to take off the random file extensions on the end and be left with just

```
name_1.23.ps
```

Other questions similar to this use '.' as a delimator but this removes everything after name_1.

I want to do this on the command line (in tcsh or bash)

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: You may use a regex: `/^\w*.\w*.\w*/gm` or just split the string by `.` and take the first 3 items.

Comment: So given a.b.c.X, where X may contain periods, you want to return always a.b.c?

Comment: yes thats correct Joni - I want to keep a.b.c and remove X

Answer (score 12, accepted):

check this if it works for your requirement:

**sed**

```
sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'
```

**grep**

```
grep -Po '.*(?=\.)'
```

test:

```
kent$  cat f
name_1.23.ps.png
name_1.23.ps.best
name_1.23.ps
name_1.23.ps

#sed:
kent$  sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' f
name_1.23.ps
name_1.23.ps
name_1.23
name_1.23

#grep
kent$  grep -Po '.*(?=\.)' f
name_1.23.ps
name_1.23.ps
name_1.23
name_1.23
```

**EDIT** from the comments. I feel it would be new requirement:

**grep**

```
kent$  grep -o '.*\.ps' f                                                                                         
name_1.23.ps
name_1.23.ps
name_1.23.ps
name_1.23.ps
```

**sed**

```
kent$  sed 's/\(.*\.ps\)\..*/\1/' f
name_1.23.ps
name_1.23.ps
name_1.23.ps
name_1.23.ps
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me as it leaves some files with .ps and some with no extension at all

Comment: it removes **only the last** extension. as you wished. if it didn't work for you for some cases, pls show the example input. @user1958508

Comment: I want to take off anything after '.ps' but if it ends with only '.ps' keep it as the same.

Comment: @user1958508 is `.ps` always in your filename?

Comment: @user1958508 see the EDIT in answer.

Answer (score 11):

We can use the bash string operation that deletes the shortest match of a glob patten from the back of a string. We will use ".*" for the glob pattern.

```
filename="name_1.23.ps.png"                                                      
echo ${filename%.*}                                                              
# the above output name_1.23.ps
```

This answer is more for my own reference as I come back to this page a few times.
(It does not satisfy the OP's additional requirement of keeping the original string the same if it ends with only '.ps').

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
string="name_1.23.ps.png"
array=(${string//./ })
echo "${array[0]}.${array[1]}.${array[2]}"
```